# is there any DC-Hull code in java

Tags: java

Hi
I know its algorithm ,is there any code in java for it?there is a code for quick hull in java but there is not any code for this one ,is there?
thanks

Comment: What is DC Hull?  Never heard of it.  Please explain.

Comment: it is one way of convex-hull which its time performance is O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**this**](http://www.dr-mikes-maths.com/DP-convex-hull-java-code.html) as a starting point, I don't know of any DC specific implementations out there.